# Different prononunciations of "consummate"

Tags: verbs, adjectives, pronunciation, stress

How can one remember the pronunciations of [consummate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/consummate?q=consummate), which depend on its state as a verb or adjective?

I venture that because its verbal definition involves intercourse, thus the "mate" rhymes with the single noun mate. But is this right?

Moreover, what's the rationale or reasoning behind the differences?

Comment: Note that the same pattern occurs in the cases of _appropriate_ (verb) and _appropriate_ (adjective), _deliberate_ (verb) and _deliberate_ (adjective), _separate_ (verb) and _separate_ (adjective), and _animate_ (verb) and _animate_ (adjective); only the members of the last pair end in -mate.

Comment: @SvenYargs: Consummate observation! My deep thanks! Please feel free to recast it as an answer for which I'll upvote!

Comment: Consummate as a verb did not start life related to *mate*. That use is a euphemism, as in *close the deal*. While strongly married to the baby-making thing, *consummate* applies to other final touches. Seal the deal with an X or with an F.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever the stress in such -***ate*** words is not on the final syllable, then generally the last syllable will be:

- for verbs: /eɪt/  [long vowel]
- for adjectives: /ət/  [short schwa vowel]

The speaker may use a glottal stop in either case as an allophone of the /t/.

When the word stress does fall on the final syllable, however, the word will end in /eɪt/ regardless, even if it is an adjective:

- irate /aɪˈreɪt/

If the word is a verb, then usually  the suffix -***tion*** can be used to convert it into a noun. You will note in this case that the /eɪ/ sound will not change, as it will be full length in this position. This is because it will take the main stress in the word. The -***tion*** suffix actually requires the preceding syllable to be stressed.

In other words if the word is a verb it should have the same vowel sound as the -***tion*** noun. It's not really a case of a rationale, though. It's more just how the language has evolved - not how it's been designed!

Comment: @lapressentiment thanks for alerting me to the typo!

Comment: Note that _irate_ can also be pronounced with initial stress (I would personally never have final stress), though it retains its /ei/ diphthong. The same goes for adjectives like _innate_, _prostrate_ (which to my knowledge always has initial stress), etc.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet *Prostrate* I'd certainly agree with. But as a generalisation/guide the rule above is pretty sound - *prostrate* is one the reasons for the 'generally' hedge.  *Irate* and *innate*, though, are standardly second syllable stress, to my knowledge and after a couple of Br and Gen Am dictionary checks. I know that in some non-standard American varieties *irate* can be first syllable. :)

Comment: @Janus: OED says of **prostrate** (verb) **Brit. /prɒˈstreɪt/, /prəˈstreɪt/, U.S. /ˈprɑˌstreɪt/**. That's how I say it (noun/adjective: stress first syllable, verb: stress *second* syllable). Which slightly surprises me since I have the general impression Americans are more likely that Brits to distinguish vern/noun forms on the basis of stress placement.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Interesting observation FF. Do you know what it says for the adj.? Don't have access to OED at the mo ...

Comment: @Araucaria: In this specific case, the *adjectival* sense shares pronunciation with the *noun*, the same as ***record, present, reject***. I don't know if there any/many such words where the adjective sides with the verb, but it seems to me the more common split is ***verb*** on one side, and everything else on the other. I'm guessing the noun usually existed first and represents the "default", but at some point people start trying to distinguish the (initially, less common) *verb* sense by pronunciation.

Answer (score 2):

*Consummate* is one of a fairly large number of *-ate* words in English whose adjective and verb forms are always, usually, or often pronounced differently. Here are 23 other words that follow this pattern:

> aggregate
>
> animate
>
> appropriate
>
> approximate
>
> concatenate
>
> correlate
>
> degenerate
>
> deliberate
>
> designate
>
> deviate
>
> duplicate
>
> enervate
>
> incarnate
>
> legitimate
>
> obligate
>
> precipitate
>
> predicate
>
> predominate
>
> regenerate
>
> reticulate
>
> separate
>
> striate
>
> terminate

This list includes the following endings: two *-cate*, two *-gate*, three *-iate*, two *-late*, three *-mate*, five *-nate*, four *-rate*, one *-tate*, and one *-vate.*

According to Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003), the adjective form of *designate* is more often pronounced like the verb form than not, but the only multisyllable *-ate* words I could find that the dictionary says are always pronounced the same in both their adjective and verb forms are these two:

> consecrate
>
> serrate

Another word that may be an exception is this one:

> reprobate

Unfortunately, the Eleventh Collegiate doesn't bother to provide a pronunciation for this word as an adjective; but I believe that it is usually (if not always) voiced the same as the verb form. The adjective *fenestrate* would constitute a fourth exception, if the Collegiate Dictionary listed a verb form of that word as well, but the closest it comes to such a verb is *defenestrate*, which doesn't have a matching adjective form.

The most striking thing about the *-ate* words listed here is that all but two of them (*serrate* and *striate*) are at least three syllables long. In English, most two-syllable *-ate* verbs ("*collate*, *create*, *debate*, *deflate*, *dilate*, *locate*, *mandate*, *migrate*, *relate*, *truncate*, etc.) do not have identical adjective forms, and most two-syllable -ate adjectives (*oblate*, *ornate*, *ovate*, *palmate*, etc.) have no matching verb.

Comment: I should add _prostrate_ (which Janus Bahs Jacquet brings up in a comment above) to the list of clear exceptions, alongside _consecrate_, _reprobate_, and _serrate_.

Answer (score -1):

The word, as a verb, actually means "to bring to its highest level", and as a verb, it is pronounced with a "long a" in the final syllable (to rhyme with "mate"). Its only association with sexual intercourse is in raising a marriage (or other relationship) to something beyond the mere social form -- an unconsummated marriage can be declared null (as if it had never happened).

As an adjective, it mean "of the highest calibre/quality", and is pronounced with an unstressed final syllable (nearly rhyming with "it" in most dialects).

Comment: As a *noun,* though, per OP's question, it refers to a kind of broth, pronounced with the accent on the final syllable, but the *t* silent. ;-)

Comment: @BrianDonovan - are you referring to *consommé*?

Comment: @Brian: Never heard of that one. Are you sure you're not thinking of [**consommé**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consomm%C3%A9)?

Comment: @bye: It's worth noting that (I *think*) the general pattern tends to be that the stress in a verb form moves to the first syllable in noun *or* adjective forms. That's certainly what happens in *present, upset, permit, absent,* etc.

Comment: @BrianDonovan _Waiter! There's a penis in my soup!_ You've made my day (although I think your smiley should have been in bold) **;-)**

Comment: @Frank: apparently it should have been; (bye & FF): as we say in informal register on our side of the pond, "dja think?"

Comment: @BrianDonovan Tsk, Tsk, this is no place for humour. I'm Inspector Buttress of the Joke Police, Soup and Starters Division, Special Flying Squad and you're nicked.

Comment: @BrianDonovan - Believe it or not, as you will, there are a lot of non-native users of English hereabouts. Humour is fair game (as is wordplay) - $_DEITY knows I've committed a bit of it myself here - but promoting confusion isn't.